# Is there a way to tell if a boot loader can be unlocked before purchase?

Tags: bootloader

For example are boot loaders unlockable only if the phone is branded and comes with a contract? If I bought a phone of Amazon.com would I likely be able to unlock the boot loader or is it really just luck of the draw?

Comment: It depends entirely on what device it is.

Comment: Most probably if its a branded phone and it has been launched from a while then you can search it on Google to check out if the Bootloader is unlock-able or not?